# Xamarin page navigation

Tags: xamarin

[image]

How do i make a page slide into the Content section when i choose the menu options ?

Currently when i select a menu option it opens a brand new page on top of my main page(page on the right).
I want it to work like html IFrame. So i want the page to load without refreshing the Menu toolbar on the right page - and of course the menu must disappear when the new page slide in.

Here is the code i use to call my another page from the menu option :

C#

```
 [Activity(Label = "FlyInMenu", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            //for calling the menu opiton
            var menu = FindViewById<FlyOutContainer>(Resource.Id.FlyOutContainer);
            var menuButton = FindViewById(Resource.Id.MenuButton);
            menuButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                menu.AnimatedOpened = !menu.AnimatedOpened;
            };

            //redirect
            var myProfileOption = FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout11);
            myProfileOption.Click += delegate {  
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyProfileActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }
    }
```

AXML

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:duplicateParentState="true">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:layout_width="29.0dp"
        android:layout_height="44.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Option1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Another question is that how do i implement a loading page between the calls ? I.e when i click on a menu option
i would like to see a loading page an then the destination page.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `NavigationView` and `DrawerLayout` which is provided by the [Android Design Support Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=vswin).

Xamarin provides bindings for this library. They also have a [example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/) on how to use this NavigationView (see section "Effective Navigation in Android")

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here : http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/01/navigation-drawer-using-material-design.html

This tutorial switch pages smoothly, without flickering or affecting the toolbar.